# Re-using nuget packages across VS 2010 solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nuget-package

I just started using [Nuget package manager](http://www.nuget.org/) and something is confusing me.  When I install a package it is installed per-project or per-solution and if I want to use the same package in different solutions or projects I have to re-install it. I would like to be able to add the package to a new solution just the way I can add local assembly or image file. How to do that?

Comment: When you installs package on first time, it is downloaded to your local store, then every time it is will installed, it will from local store if no updates are available.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yes i know nuget is caching the packages, but can't i just select some installed packages and add them to the current project ?

Comment: If you want to do than...you should 1) Add an assembly reference to the assembly and 2) Update web.config with the correct settings. NuGet automates all these tasks..

Comment: Downloading packages is, by design, per solution. On the solution node you can select "Manage packages" and install downloaded packages into any project you wish. This is the normal use case. If you want to reuse packages across solutions, you can create your own, local cache. There are several good guides on the internet. =)

Comment: @J.Steen can you point to such link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you do that is like this:
copy the dll/dlls from the project directory into a folder that you create for example in c:\DLLs\ and then for every new project that you want to use that package, just reference it in the add reference...